# Templating engine - JS side or PHP side? Which is better?

Tags: javascript, php, templates

I have a templating engine for dynamic page and table rows generation.

The idea is like most templating techniques, that is to prepare an HTML template (visually designing it) and use {{variable_name}} in the HTML block and do a search/replace routine.

At the moment, what i'm doing (and have work flawlessly for months) is that JS sends the HTML template block (say the dynamic/loopable row in a data table (the whole html code) to PHP where it is treated as a template string.. and PHP loops through the results of the SQL query and doing a preg_replace on the template string.

```
$html_content .= doTemplate("name,address,age",$template_string);
```

That $html_content is then outputted as a JSON object back to the client browser ..

I know i'm moving more bytes than necessary to and from the backend since my output contains HTML code instead of just the data, but i figured this is a small tradeoff since PHP processing the template replacement is faster than client browser (JS).

This time, I am thinking of doing the templating/string replacements in JS, but im wondering how much slower JS really is doing string.replace routines.

Is it really that much slower?

Comment: Something to remember is that not all users will see the same speed when running JavaScript.  Older browsers may run scripts slower than the most recent browsers available.  If the user has little RAM left then it may run slower on their system again.  In my opinion it would be better to run it via the PHP as everyone will experience the same processing time, just the render time of the users specific browser would be the defining factor then.  I have found this link that compares them both for you though... http://benchmarks.ro/2011/02/str_replace-vs-preg_replace/

Comment: you make a good point Simon, bout preserving same experience across all users as much as possible... so i guess the extra bytes of data generating and sending HTML code from PHP to client is worth that.